Only two of three Jabber clients receive messages sent by ejabberdctl send_message
I want to use Jabber to notify myself about events on the server.
I have been looking for a very long time for a proper Jabber client that can send messages from the Linux command line, but found either some scripts like sendxmpp, which no longer works today, or interactive ncurses-based console clients.
Then I found the command ejabberdctl send_message which does exactly what I want to some extent.
The main problem is that when I send a message to my account from the name of a specific service Jabber-account, not all programs logged in with my account receive messages.
More specifically, the Xabber client on my old phone and the Gajim client on my PC receive messages (both were installed at the same time, shortly after I installed ejabberd), but the Xabber client on my new phone does not receive messages sent via ejabberdctl send_message (but receives messages sent via normal Jabber client).
Both Xabber clients on phones are of the same version and have same priorities.
When I send messages from the name of this service Jabber-account while logged in from the regular Jabber client (Xabber of Gajim), all my phones receive the message.
Could you help me to determine the cause of this selective behavior?
I am using Ejabberd v 17.07.
